# Protect fields from edit or deletion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3

I was wondering if there is any way to protect fields so that users cannot delete or edit them. With that being said, a 'superuser' would need to be able to edit and delete at will.

working in python with arcpy; arcgis 10.3

Comment: this is possible with SDE databases and user connections/roles, I'm not aware of this capability in file or personal geodatabases

Comment: I wasn't thinking so. I know shape_area and shape_length are locked down and I was hoping to be able to do the same to others.

Comment: I believe geometry attributes are only locked in the sense that they are derived from the geometry and so change with spatial edits. Maybe using a [viewer software](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer) is a good alternative for certain users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a field in a FGDB, you can mark it as `required` which will not allow you to delete it.

```
>>> gdb = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management('C:/temp', 'temp')[0]
>>> table = arcpy.CreateTable_management(gdb, 'table')[0]
>>> arcpy.AddField_management(table, 'a', field_is_required=True)    
>>> arcpy.DeleteField_management(table, 'a')

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>  
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 3479, in DeleteField     raise e ExecuteError:
Failed to execute.
Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 001334: Cannot delete required field a
Failed to execute (DeleteField).
```

From the help on [`Add Field`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-field.htm):

> Fields set as required are permanent and you will not be able to
>   delete them with future processing. To allow for deletion at a later
>   time set the field to non-required (the default).

Comment: Couldn't you place the table of protected data in a folder where only the superuser has read/write permissions, then join the tables together?

Comment: a lot of overhead, but I guess that's a way around it.

Comment: I think the provided answer is about as close as I am going to get. I would like to be able to do this outside of geodatabases but it does not look possible.